# Not Receiving Message When Publishing using redis in laravel api

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, publish-subscribe

I am using **laravel api as a backend and vue as a front end.** These are standalone projects. When I am hitting the api which publishes after redis connection like

```
$redis = Redis::connection();

$redis->publish('new_message_sent',json_encode($request->all()));
```

It does not do anything. Infact when I hit the api (using postman) and return the $redis object, it returns me an empty object.

Here is the node server code for subscription

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
   console.log("Client Connecteddddd");
   var redisClient = redis.createClient();
   redisClient.subscribe("new_message_sent");


   redisClient.on("new_message_sent", function(channel, message) {
       message = JSON.parse(message);
       console.log(message);    
   });

   redisClient.on("disconnect", function() {
       redisClient.quit();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I've stumbled on a similar situation where I'd expect my Redis client to receive the published message from Laravel's `Redis` Facade but it didn't.

I expected `Redis::publish('foo', 'bar')` to be picked up when running `SUBSCRIBE foo` in `redis-cli`.

After running `MONITOR` in `redis-cli` I noticed that the published channel name is different than I expected - `{app-name}_database_foo`.

This is configured in `database.php` in the `redis.options.prefix` key, which is `env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),` by default, knowing this / changing this will help.

Comment: Thank you for this. This helped me understand why the same redis chanel in nodejs was not receiving channel events

Comment: I wish I had seen this earlier. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

What does your subscription code look like?

The receiving end for pub/sub with Redis should look something like this:

```
  Redis::subscribe(['your-channel'], function ($message) {
            echo $message;
        });
```

This would be a long running process. This would run and echo anything that is published to 'your-channel' until something interrupts it.

If you aspire to get the information to the browser for an end user, you will need an extra step such as a websocket.

The nature of pub/sub means it would never be aware of messages send before the subscribe() happens, only those that happen while it is running.

For publishing, you shouldn't need to resolve the connection first.

```
Redis::publish('new_message_sent', json_encode($request->all()));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/redis

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have updated the question with my subscription code. I am using node server to subscribe

Comment: So you aren't seeing      console.log(message);    log messages as expected? Are you seeing    console.log("Client Connecteddddd"); log? Since you have two different technology stacks with redis in the middle, it might be worthwhile to setup a redis client of some sort to inspect the pub/sub channel. This will help you understand if the error is in getting the data published, or in the subscription to the channel.

Comment: No. I am not seeing both of these consoles But in my component(in vuejs) inside connect() function (which is inside socket:{}), I am seeing a console which is console.log("Socket connected");

Comment: If I return $redis (in api) after publishing, it displays an empty object. Do you know anything about that. I mean it should display something rather than being empty. Am I right??

Comment: I see in the above code you are resolving Redis::connection() into a variable and trying to call publish() against that variable. You likely just want Redis::publish(). I've edited my answer to include this. Does that help move it forward?

Comment: And also I told you in the previous comment that  console.log("Client Connecteddddd"); does not show. I just noticed that it is showing in the node server console but the  console.log(message); is not showing.

Comment: A good next step might be to install a redis client such as https://redis.io/topics/rediscli so that you can see what is/isn't getting to redis. At this point it's hard to know if it's the publish that is failing to write to redis or the subscription failing subscribe.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me on this issue...Somehow, I have made it work...Both publish and subscription are working now but subscription is happening twice i.e node server shows that the io.on("connection",function(){}) this code runs twice and hence the subscription code...do you know anything about this??

Comment: Nothing stands out to me as likely to cause dupliation, but a redis client might be still be of help with that.  It might be the same data getting published twice rather than the subscribe happening twice. Being able to see what goes through redis gives you a lot of insight.